# Indentation of Columns environment inside itemize

Tags: beamer, indentation, columns

I've noticed that in Beamer a "Columns" environment placed inside an "itemize" environment does not respect the indentation for items:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
    \begin{columns}[t] % contents are top vertically aligned
      \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} 
        Contents of first column \\ split into two lines
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} 
        Contents of second column \\ split into two lines
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\item item 2    
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} % 

\end{document}
```

Is this behaviour normal ? Should not an indentation be included to align the columns to the item content ?

I know I can fix this by inserting in the beginning an empty column as:

```
\begin{column}{\leftmargini}
\end{column}
```

but I'm wondering whether there is a native, more elegant solution.

Comment: what about a `tabular` inside the item?

Comment: Not solving the problem, but your columns are too wide. They have to be less then 1 textwidth, as they come with small margins and a separation between the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you should turn around the usage of the environments.  On the outside, use `columns`-environment, to define the layout of that specific slide.  Than fill your columns with contents, for example an `itemize`-environment.

The `itemize`-environment does not offer a `columns`-environment and hence must fail as it did in your example.

## EDIT

As suggested: this is the usage with an `tabular`-like environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}           % adapts columnwidth
\usepackage{array}              % for creating new columntypes
\usepackage{ragged2e}           % for line wrapping within words

%% Define a new column for your tabular in the itemize environment.
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Two columns in \texttt{itemize}}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{2}{L} @{}} % @{} to remove
                                % white space at the left and right
                                % border of the table
      Contents of first column \newline split into two lines
   & Contents of second column \newline split into two lines 
    \end{tabularx}
  \item item 2    
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And its result:

[image]

Comment: ok, but turning environments around does not make much sense in this case: conceptually, I have a list of items among which just one need a splitted layout ... Anyway what you're saying is that "columns" is an environment of the "frame" environments and so is not said to behave regularly inside an "itemize" environment ?

Comment: @dario: You are correct.  It is an environment of the `frame` and not of `itemize`.  If you need two or more columns in your `itemize`-environment, you'll have to try another approach, for example a `tabular`-environment.